# Is there a way of restarting an app when coming back from background?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, multitasking

I want to be able to restart the app when coming back from background. So if the user selects the app again it should start as if it were the first time it's open. I've been googling but couldn't find a way of doing this.

I was thinking in just add the main view of the app in `applicationWillEnterForeground`, but It would be great if I can deallocate resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't restart an app. What you can do is disable background support, so your app always completely terminates when closing.

> "...you can explicitly opt out of the
>   background execution model by adding
>   the **UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend** key to
>   your application’s **Info.plist** file and
>   setting its value to **YES**."

Source: [Opting Out of Background Execution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5).